# appending date time and passing it to create file

Tags: java

i am trying to append current date time to filename and pass it to creation of file...so basically this is my code

```
public class Main {

    //....

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String d =dt.format(date).toString();
        String fname = "spy1";
        File dir = new File("E:\\");
        File f = new File(dir,fname+d+".txt");
        if(f.createNewFile())
        {
            System.out.println("file creates");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("file not created ");
        }
    }
}
```

this my code please help me in how to append current date time to file name and create the file with mentioned directory

Answer (score 6):

Forward slash, `/`, and colon, `:`, are not permitted characters for a filename on windows. From [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#file_and_directory_names)

```
Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode
characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255),
except for the following:

- The following reserved characters:

  +  (greater than)
  + : (colon)
  + " (double quote)
  + / (forward slash)
  + \ (backslash)
  + | (vertical bar or pipe)
  + ? (question mark)
  + * (asterisk)

- Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
- Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31,
except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed.
For more information about file streams, see File Streams.
- Any other character that the target file system does not allow.
```

The date format string needs to change. For example:

```
DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
```

Comment: Meaning, time can also be separated by dash which results in a example filename like `Screenshot_2018-07-31_15-03-28.png`.